# Having trouble setting icon

Tags: java

Still a newb at this, I'm always getting "non-static method cannot be referenced from static content" alot... not just this... :(

I've tried the following using this vid; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40ikcEonWng

```
public class Home extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {
  public Home() {
    initComponents();
    setIcon();
  }

    public static void main(String args[]){

    }

  private void setIcon() {
     setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("?Images/icon.png")));

  }
 }
```

Also tried putting this in the main method but still same error (for 2nd line);

```
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("/Images/icon.png");
    Home.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all your setIcon() is private make it as public and You are directly calling that function without making an object..If you want to do so make setIcon as static but its not a right thing to do for setter function..

Comment: If you want to call any of your methods from main, create an instance of Home and use it:

Home home = new Home();
home.setIconImage(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create an instance of the Home class.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Home extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {

    public Home() {
        initComponents();
        setIcon();
    }

    private void initComponents(){}
    @Override public void run() {}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Home home = new Home();     
    }

    private void setIcon() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/Images/icon.png")));
    }

}
```